# How can I Minimize this function with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I wrote the following function in MATLAB:

```
function EX_EFFICIENCY=EXERGY_EFFICIENCY_FUNCTION(CR,ER,PC,T0,P0)
```

I used the following order (ga):

```
x = ga(@EXERGY_EFFICIENCY_FUNCTION,5)
```

But it gets the error:

> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in EXERGY_EFFICIENCY_FUNCTION (line 22)
>   T7p=T0.*(PC.^((k-1)./k));
>
> Error in createAnonymousFcn>@(x)fcn(x,FcnArgs{:}) (line 11) fcn_handle
>   = @(x) fcn(x,FcnArgs{:});
>
> Error in makeState (line 47)
>               firstMemberScore = FitnessFcn(state.Population(initScoreProvided+1,:));
>
> Error in gaunc (line 40) state =
>   makeState(GenomeLength,FitnessFcn,Iterate,output.problemtype,options);
>
> Error in ga (line 398)
>               [x,fval,exitFlag,output,population,scores] = gaunc(FitnessFcn,nvars, ...
>
> Caused by:
>       Failure in initial user-supplied fitness function evaluation. GA cannot continue.

How can I minimize this function?

Comment: Minimize? Optimize? You mean fix? `ga` wants the handle to a function with one input argument. You give it one that needs 5 arguments. That will not work, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the variables you want to minimize over? All five `CR,ER,PC,T0,P0`? Then you need to tell `ga` to use a length-5-vector and deal its elements to the input arguments of the function. Like this:

`xopt = ga(@(x) EXERGY_EFFICIENCY_FUNCTION(x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5)), 5);`

You can also fix some and optimize over the others of course, like this:

`xopt = ga(@(x) EXERGY_EFFICIENCY_FUNCTION(x(1),x(2),PC,T0,P0), 2);`

optimizes `CR`, `ER` for fixed values of `PC`,`T0`, and `P0`.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.